# MVC Parameter Binding from JSON into multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm receiving JSON data from this method:

```
function CallAPI(controllerName, functionName, sendData, callback) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajax.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                callback(response);
            }
            else {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.open("POST", "http://" + window.location.host + "/API/" + controllerName + "/" + functionName, true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    ajax.send(JSON.stringify(sendData));
}

function someRequest() {
    var data = {};
    data.userID = 1;
    data.someValue = 20;
    CallAPI("Home", "Add", data, function (response) {
        if(response) {
            alert(response.Message); //This property always exist
        }
        else {
            alert("internet/connection error.");
        }
    });
}
```

And my Controller is:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Add(int userID, int someValue)
{
    //Here!
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new GenericResponseAPI() { Status = false, Message = "Generic Message." });
}
```

I can create a model and MVC would bind it accordingly, but I have so many of these requests that I don't want to create various models (or a big one containing all of the properties), but instead have these simple functions with basic type parameters like this.

What do I need to do to be able to work with the controller function above, without changing the content-type of the incoming message?

**Edit:** I found a workaround with this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Add(JObject jObject)
{
    int userID = (int)jObject.getValue("userID").ToObject(typeof(Int32));
    int someValue = (int)jObject.getValue("someValue").ToObject(typeof(Int32));

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? Are parameters not getting bound in the way you expect?

Comment: @Shoe Nope, the function isn't even called and I get a resource not found error in javascript. If I change the javascript caller to send via querystring and not json post data, it works though.

Comment: Try changing `System.Web.Http.HttpPost` to `System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost`

Comment: @Shoe I get the same `"The server responded with a status of 404"` error.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the stringified object?

Comment: @Shoe this? `{ "userID": 1, "someValue": "" }` I'm looking on how I get the entire post request (not just the body content) but I can't find how...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the reason is that your `function` signature is:

```
function CallAPI(controllerName, functionName, sendData, callback)
```

and you're calling

```
CallAPI("Home", "Add", function (response) { ... })
```

So you're never actually sending data in the format MVC is expecting.

I'd double check this by using something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and by debugging your JavaScript code using your browsers dev-tools.

Comment: That was a typo, I accidentaly forgot to type that in the question (but it's in the code). Sorry! (I know it's working, I have various other functions being called and they're working, but it's the amount that keeps increasing and I want to find a way to deal without having to create new models for all the requests)

Comment: @Danicco I suggest updating the question in that case! :P